# I'm trying to remove information at the beginning and end of a list, but some of the uppercase letters mess up the code

Tags: python, list

Below is the aforementioned list.

```
memberList = ['uuid_e04a043abc334bd1a2fbd167bdce1673[MVP+] IgrisGuild Master2020/07/21 '
 '02:35:052020/08/09 01:52:37',
 'uuid_1f12bce8313040a7978d5c51ceb9d82d[VIP] mistercintPrince2020/08/01 '
 '00:31:342020/08/08 23:47:53',
 'uuid_405e46954f804487ae9c18689f0c351b[MVP+] zoucePrince2020/08/06 '
 '20:11:222020/08/08 22:02:04',
 'uuid_a2b224ba7c5d42ee8d46b2c08297cef5 viellythedivelonBaron2020/07/25 '
 '02:54:022020/08/08 22:53:56',
 'uuid_ac8f62b779624750ad287320f2505cea[MVP+] Louis7864Baron2020/07/26 '
 '19:04:422020/08/09 02:22:07',
 'uuid_8a350042ed6a474ba4b186e6126e0be1[VIP] Broadside1138Baron2020/07/29 '
 '04:07:072020/08/09 03:01:48',
 'uuid_031c3178bfd04099b34301185d1182f3[VIP] KuttaBaron2020/07/31 '
 '02:15:202020/08/09 03:16:53',
 'uuid_63f8371a69bc404d855afd61f5775db2[VIP+] BabaloopsBaron2020/08/06 '
 '23:34:452020/08/08 22:52:44',
 'uuid_559b3816586c4db5909fb0ca4f2b56e8[VIP+] SparkleDuck9Baron2020/08/08 '
 '23:17:132020/08/09 02:12:58',
 'uuid_c469d1cbc4344a36a110664fdc1ba571[VIP] TooLongOfAUserNaNoble2020/08/01 '
 '03:54:592020/08/09 02:57:22']
```

This line removes part of it that is universal to every single object in the list.

```
memberList = [e[37:-38] for e in memberList]
```

The last two lines trim off the rest, but for some, it trims too much

```
members = [re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", member.split(" ")[1]).split()[0] for member in memberList]
print(members)
```

The output I want would look something like this:

['Igris', 'mistercint', 'zouce', 'viellythedivelon', 'Louis7864', 'Broadside138', 'Kutta', 'Babaloops', SparkleDuck9, 'TooLongOfAUserNa']

Thanks for your consideration, I am very new to this platform and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the guideline for the split? For ex: `'TooLongOfAUserNaNoble2020/08/01'`, how do you decide how long you want to extract?

Comment: The person below answered it great, but I just wanted to say thanks for the reply as well. The answer to your question is that there are certain words after there name that make them unique such as 'Baron', 'Noble', 'Prince', and 'Guild Master.' Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your split you want to remove last upper case character to end of string.

```
members = [re.sub("[A-Z][^A-Z]+$", "", member.split(" ")[1]) for member in memberList]
```

Then you get

```
['Igris', 'mistercint', 'zouce', 'viellythedivelon', 'Louis7864', 'Broadside1138', 'Kutta', 'Babaloops', 'SparkleDuck9', 'TooLongOfAUserNa']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It works just as I intended! I would not know how many rabbit holes I would've gone down if it weren't for your guys' help!